# How to identify PID of process that is generating lots of ICMP ping requests?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, rhel7, icmp

I have a box that is generating lots of outgoing ICMP requests. I am able to see a few happening every second with `tcpdump -nni ens192 icmp`. However, I don't have anyway of tracing these back to the PID that is causing them. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command

```
ss -npa | grep -e '???' -e icmp
```

I get this result while running ping:

```
???     UNCONN  0    0    0.0.0.0:1 0.0.0.0:* users:(("ping",pid=7174,fd=3)) 
icmp6   UNCONN  0    0    *:58      *:*       users:(("ping",pid=7174,fd=4))
```

While there are different ways to send ICMP packets, it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

use ss

```
 ss -apw |grep icmp
```

answer:

```
UNCONN     0      0    *:icmp   *:*  users:(("ping",19122,3))
```